# what are the different between zealout and fanatic in english american?

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-difference

I saw in a dictionary this word : **zealout** and its meaning is **fanatic** my question what way is more common say between people from USA?

this way:

**I am fanatic of soccer I love soccer** or  **I am zealout of occer I love soccer**

I think is more common  say **fanatic**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say a *soccer fan* or *soccer fanatic*.  Using "fan" is rather more common. This is better than "a fanatic of soccer".

"Zealot" (notice the spelling) suggests someone who has very strong opinions about something *and tries to make other people have them too*. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/zealot)

The word zealot has rather negative connotations.  A soccer fan will spend lots of money to buy a replica kit for their team.  But a zealot will organise "anti-baseball demonstrations".  We might talk about a religious zealot, in a negative way.

The expression you want is "fan" or perhaps "fanatic".

Comment: okay but where could I use the word "zealout" when I am talk  with a american english?

Comment: First spell it correctly.  "Zealot".  You can use "zealot" when you are talking about a zealot: Someone with strong beliefs who tries to make other people believe the same as he does.